# Am I converting properly from "const char *" to "TCHAR*"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, char, type-conversion, tchar

I'm trying to pass a process name as a TCHAR to the following void:

```
void GetBaseAddressByName(DWORD pID, TCHAR *pN)
```

By doing it like this:

```
GetBaseAddressByName(aProcs[i], (TCHAR*)"Process.exe");
```

So my question is: is what I am doing correct? Because I have tried both TEXT("Process.exe") and _T("Process.exe") with my project's Character Set both on Multi-Bite and Unicode and it just tells me that

```
argument of type "const char*" is incompatible with parameter of type "TCHAR*"
```

Comment: "Process.exe" is a `const char *`. If that function tries to modify the contents, your program will crash. Use a temp buffer instead: `TCHAR temp[] = "Process.exe";`

Comment: Besides the `const` you could be using `UNICODE` and then `TCHAR` would still be incompatible with `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(TCHAR*)"Process.exe"` is not a valid type-cast.  It will "work" when the project charset is set to ANSI/MBCS, but it will produce garbage if the charset is set to Unicode.

Using `TEXT("Process.exe")` is the correct way to make a string literal use `TCHAR` characters.

```
GetBaseAddressByName(aProcs[i], TEXT("Process.exe"));
```

However, you need to change your `pN` parameter to `const TCHAR *` (or `LPCTSTR`) instead:

```
void GetBaseAddressByName(DWORD pID, const TCHAR *pN);
```

```
void GetBaseAddressByName(DWORD pID, LPCTSTR pN);
```

A string literal is const data, and you cannot pass a pointer-to-const-data where a pointer-to-non-const-data is expected (without casting the `const` away with `const_cast`).  That is why you were still getting errors when trying to use the `TEXT()`/`_T()` macros.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no.  TCHAR maps to either `char` or `wchar_t` depending on your project's Unicode/Multi-byte setting.  So, in general, a cast like that is either unnecessary or incorrect.  The correct way, as you said, is to use either the `TEXT` or `_T` macro.  The reason you're getting an error is that you're trying to pass a `const` character string to a function that expects a mutable character string.  The safeset way to get around the error is to copy your constant string into a local `TCHAR` buffer and then pass that to `GetBaseAddressByName`.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to have a TCHAR array first, then copy into it.

```
#include "atlstr.h"
char const *  procName = "processName.exe";
TCHAR szName [128];
_tcscpy(szName, A2T(procName));
GetBaseAddressByName(aProcs[i], szName);
```

As suggested by @Remy Lebeau in the comments, `procName` can be defined as `TCHAR const * procName = TEXT("processName.exe");`.

Comment: There is no need to use `A2T()` in this example, just change `procName` to `TCHAR const * procName = TEXT("processName.exe");` instead, and then you can use `_tcscpy(szName, procName);`

Answer (score 0):

You need a L, like `L"Process.exe"`. Unicode strings are specified with L"".

That said, there is no reason to use TCHAR. Use unicode all the time, if doing Windows work only.